Is usfca's Masters in Data Science Program good?
Here's the link to the program:
https://www.usfca.edu/arts-sciences/programs/graduate/data-science
Does anyone know if it's any good? I like the curriculum and it's a 1 year program. In addition to the course work, you work 9 months for a local company 16 hours per week. What are your thoughts guys?
